# jest has 'missing semicolon error' on valid typescript code

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Node.js v16.14.0 npm 8.3.1

I copied this code from a working project of typescript and jest and for some reason my configuration must be bad.  I am getting missing semi-colon pointing to the colon on this line in every test

```
let userSvc: UserService;
```

I created a very very small project https://github.com/deanhiller/userServiceJs and am simply trying to get jest working.  This command works just fine....

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc
```

How do I get jest working?

I have the following package.json file (found if you click the github link above of course)

```
   {
        "name": "userservice",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "typescript interview",
        "main": "index.js",
        "scripts": {
        "test": "test"
        },
        "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/deanhiller/userServiceJs.git"
        },
        "author": "Dean",
        "license": "ISC",
        "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/deanhiller/userServiceJs/issues"
        },
        "homepage": "https://github.com/deanhiller/userServiceJs#readme",
        "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.19.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.19.4",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.18.6",
        "@types/jest": "^29.1.2",
        "babel-jest": "29.2.0",
        "jest": "29.2.0",
        "ts-generic-collections-linq": "1.0.7",
        "ts-jest": "29.0.3",
        "typescript": "4.8.4"
        }
     }
```

I have the following tsconfig.json (again, found in the github link above)

```
           {
           "compilerOptions": {
           "experimentalDecorators": true,
           "target": "es6",
           "outDir": "dist",
           "lib": [
           "dom",
           "dom.iterable",
           "esnext"
           ],
           "sourceMap": true,
           "allowJs": false,
           "noImplicitAny": true,
           "skipLibCheck": true,
           "esModuleInterop": true,
           "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
           "strict": true,
           "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
           "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
           "module": "esnext",
           "moduleResolution": "node",
           "resolveJsonModule": true,
           "isolatedModules": true,
           "noEmit": false,
           "jsx": "react-jsx"
           },
           "include": [
           "src"
           ]
      }
```

Comment: were you able to solve it. I am also getting same error.